# Replacing parts of a neural net during training using TrainingProgressFunction

Tags: neural-networks

`NetReplacePart` is interesting because it allows to change, for instance, the weights of a layer (in a net), however it does return a new net and not mutate the existing net.

`TrainingProgressFunction` on the other hand allows us to call arbitrary functions during training.

Is is possible to combine `NetReplacePart` and `TrainingProgressFunction` so that we can change the net we are currently training?

An useful application could a *soft* tying of weights in an auto encoder net. Usually tying of weights means that the decoder weight matrix is just the transposed encoder weight matrix. As far as I am aware there is currently no method to do so directly, so I though one could call a function that takes both encoder and transposed decoder matrix and replaces both by the average of the two every few batches. My naive approach of just using `Set` on the `#Net` parameter supplied to `TrainingProgressFunction` prints out the usual warnings of misusing `Set`.

Answer (score 5):

No that's not possible at the moment. We plan on exposing a mutable API so you can write your own training loop, optimizers, etc. Currently the "$MXTrainer" property is pretty close to this, but this will be higher-level: there will be a way of getting a *mutable* network that contains handles to mutable arrays, changing those arrays makes the network behave differently.